# Why Python cannot import functions from utils? (nltk)

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying both in Google Collab and Jupyter Notebooks.

In Jupyter Notebooks, presents the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 from utils import process_tweet, build_freqs

ImportError: cannot import name 'process_tweet' from 'utils' (C:\Users\Gabriel\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\utils\__init__.py)`
```

What can I do?

Previous code:

```
import nltk                                  
from nltk.corpus import twitter_samples      
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt              
import numpy as np                           

nltk.download('twitter_samples')
nltk.download('stopwords')

!pip install utils 
from utils import process_tweet, build_freqs
```

Answer (score 0):

With `!pip install utils` you've installed [some random `utils` package](https://pypi.org/project/utils/), and now when you try to import from `utils`, you end up trying to import from there.

Unless you know you need this `utils`, I'd suggest `!pip uninstall -y utils` to get rid of it.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help. The problem is that I need the functions "process_tweet" and "build_freqs" from utils. 

When I tried to uninstall and import them:
"import process_tweet, build_freqs"

the error was:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 import process_tweet, build_freqs

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'process_tweet'

Comment: You will need to get those functions from somewhere. They're probably related to whatever code you're trying to run (see the linked duplicate).

Comment: Current best practice would be `%pip install ...` and `%pip uninstall` **in modern Jupyter**. Google Colab doesn't count as that as it is sadly a highly customized fork of a very old version of Jupyter that pre-dates the addition of [the magic install commands](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) that insure installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running. The exclamation point variation doesn't insure that and so the magic versions were added in 2019. Google Colab was set up to work with exclamation.